# need help in formatted output using for loop in shell script

Tags: bash, shell, automation

I have the requirement to capture pod memory and other details in my setup.
have written small reproducible shell script as copied below.

```
LOGFILE='/root/User1/test/log'
Data=""
space="   "
e=34
f=12Mi
a=122
b=123
c=333
d=450

for i in {1..10}; do
    Data+=$space
    Data+=$a
    Data+=$space
    Data+=$b
    Data+=$space
    Data+=$c
    Data+=$space
    Data+=$d
    Data+=$space
    Data+=$e 
    Data+=$space
    Data+=$f
    printf "%s" "$Data" >> ${LOGFILE}
    echo $'\n' >> ${LOGFILE}
    $(unset ${Data})
    
done
```

The above script produces concatenated output.

```
34   12Mi   122   123   333   450

34   12Mi   122   123   333   450   34   12Mi   122   123   333   450

34   12Mi   122   123   333   450   34   12Mi   122   123   333   450   34   12Mi   122   123   333   450

34   12Mi   122   123   333   450   34   12Mi   122   123   333   450   34   12Mi   122   123   333   450   34   12Mi   122   123   333   450

34   12Mi   122   123   333   450   34   12Mi   122   123   333   450   34   12Mi   122   123   333   450   34   12Mi   122   123   333   450   34   12Mi   122   123   333   450

34   12Mi   122   123   333   450   34   12Mi   122   123   333   450   34   12Mi   122   123   333   450   34   12Mi   122   123   333   450   34   12Mi   122   123   333   450   34   12Mi   122
```

The output format what I am looking for is

```
34   12Mi   122   123   333   450

34   12Mi   122   123   333   450
 
34   12Mi   122   123   333   450

34   12Mi   122   123   333   450

34   12Mi   122   123   333   450

34   12Mi   122   123   333   450

34   12Mi   122   123   333   450

34   12Mi   122   123   333   450
```

can some one help me here to understand what mistake I am doing here.
and what could be the possible solution for this.

Comment: You might as well run your script through tools like [shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/).

Comment: `$(unset ${Data})` doesn't do anything useful, for a couple of reasons: first, because it tries to unset the contents of `Data`, rather than the variable `Data` itself (in shell syntax, you use `$` to *get* the value of a variable, not for operations on the variable itself), and second because the `$( )` runs it in a subshell (and then tries to execute its output, which makes no sense at all). Why not just use `Data=""`?

Comment: Are the blank lines in the output intentional?

Answer (score 2):

When you do `$(unset ${Data})`, you are running `unset ${Data}` *in a subshell*, and then try to run its output (the empty string) as a command. This is wrong on a few levels:

- A subshell can't affect its parent environment, and you don't want to run the output as a command anyway
- `unset` takes the *name* of the variable, not its expansion, as a parameter

The quick fix is to replace `$(unset ${Data})` with `unset Data`.

A simpler overall approach could be to skip the intermediate variable entirely, and move the redirection out of the loop:

```bash
for i in {1..10}; do
    printf '%s   ' "$e" "$f" "$a" "$b" "$c"
    printf '%s\n\n' "$d"
done >> "$LOGFILE"
```

This doesn't require `$Data` or `$space` any longer.

This prints the exact desired output you show, though the actual output you show doesn't correspond to your script, which has each line begin with three blanks. To get that, the `printf` formatting strings would have to be `'   %s'` and `'   %s\n\n'`, respectively.